# Highlight full field without fragments via Java API doesn't work - ES Version 0.18.6

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a simple sounding problem according highlighting of a field with elasticsearch version 0.18.6. What I want to do is to highlight a complete field and get the content back (either highlighted or if there are no matches then without highlighting - but always the full field content!)

On [elasticsearch.org](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/highlighting.html) I found this:

> If the **number_of_fragments value is set to 0 then no fragments are produced**, instead the **whole content of the field is returned**, and of course it is highlighted.

So I tried this to achieve what I want:

```
  final SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(indexName)
                .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                .setTypes(FEED_TYPE)
                .setQuery(queryString(query).field("title").field("description").field("keywords"))
                .addHighlightedField("title", 0, 0)
                .addHighlightedField("description", 0, 0)
                .addFields("url", "iconUrl", "keywords")
                .setSize(size)
                .setFrom(start)
                .execute().actionGet();
```

The Signature of this method is:

```
 public SearchRequestBuilder addHighlightedField(java.lang.String name, int fragmentSize, int numberOfFragments)
```

Do I miss something here? Or did I misunderstand that it only returns the full content if there is at least one term to hightlight?

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to achieve exactly what you want at the moment. The highlightFields collection contains only fields that were highlighted. You can do something like this:

```
final SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(indexName)
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
            .setTypes(FEED_TYPE)
            .setQuery(queryString(query).field("title").field("description").field("keywords"))
            .addHighlightedField("title", 0, 0)
            .addHighlightedField("description", 0, 0)
            .addFields("title", "description", "url", "iconUrl", "keywords")
            .setSize(size)
            .setFrom(start)
            .execute().actionGet();
```

It will always return you all fields in

```
response.hits().getAt(i).fields();
```

and fields that were highlighted in

```
response.hits().getAt(i).highlightFields();
```

While displaying results, you can check highlightFields() first and if a field is not present there, use fields() instead.